# normal and Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

We say that a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is *normal* if any two disjoint closed subsets of $X$ are separated by neighbourhoods.

We have that in $(\mathbb{R},\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\})$ are $$\emptyset,\mathbb{R}$$ closed subsets, and themselves are neighbourhoods with obviously $$\emptyset \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$$

So $(\mathbb{R},\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\})$ is a normal space, but $(\mathbb{R},\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\})$ is not a Hausdorff space.

This is a contradiction? Doesn`t normal ($T_4$) implies Hausdorff ($T_2$)?

Regards!

Comment: There are two different nomenclatures. One says "normal = $T_4$ + $T_1$", which implies $T_2$ [but a $T_4$-space needn't be], the other says "$T_4$ = normal + $T_1$". In the latter, a normal space need not be Hausdorff (but a $T_4$-space is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal doesn't actually imply Hausdorff; a space which is normal *and* $T_1$ is Hausdorff. Your example is a counterexample to the claim that every normal space is Hausdorff; note that your space is not $T_1$, since no single point is closed.

(It was pointed out in a comment that there's some inconsistency as to what normal and $T_4$ mean; I'm using the definition of normal that you gave, which doesn't include $T_1$.)

Comment: I thought that $T_4$ implies $T_3$, and $T_3$ implies $T_2$, and so on. So, what is the really sense in the implications between the axioms of separability?

Comment: @user183002 $T_4$ does imply $T_3$ etc., it's your definition of $T_4$ that you should check.

Comment: If you define $T_4$ and $T_3$ appropriately (i.e. define $T_4$ to be normal and Hausdorff), then $T_4 \implies T_3 \implies T_2 \implies T_1 \implies T_0$. However, as Daniel Fischer's comment points out (see also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeparationAxioms.html), some authors make different definitions.

Comment: But Kosniowski's book says that $T_4$ implies $T_1$... ¿?

Comment: What's Kosniowski's definition of $T_4$?

Comment: For two disjointed closed sets $C,D$ there are open sets $U,V$ such that $C \subset U, D \subset V$

Comment: @user183002 Without also assuming the space is $T_1$, that doesn't imply it's Hausdorff, as your example shows.